# Only extract json if field not null

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, lateral-join

I want to extract a key value from a (nullable) JSONB field. If the field is NULL, I want the record still present in my result set, but with a null field.

`customer` table:

```
id, name, phone_num, address
1, "john", 983, [ {"street":"23, johnson ave", "city":"Los Angeles", "state":"California", "current":true}, {"street":"12, marigold drive", "city":"Davis", "state":"California", "current":false}]
2, "jane", 9389, null
3, "sally", 352, [ "street":"90, park ave", "city":"Los Angeles", "state":"California", "current":true} ]
```

Current PostgreSQL query:

```
select id, name, phone_num, items.city
from customer, 
     jsonb_to_recordset(customer) as items(city str, current bool)
where items.current=true
```

It returns:

```
id, name, phone_num, city
1, "john", 983, "Los Angeles"
3, "sally", 352, "Los Angeles"
```

Required Output:

```
id, name, phone_num, city
1, "john", 983, "Los Angeles"
2, "jane", 9389, null
3, "sally", 352, "Los Angeles"
```

How do I achieve the above output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `left join lateral` instead of an implicit lateral join:

```
select c.id, c.name, c.phone_num, i.city
from customer c
left join lateral jsonb_to_recordset(c.address) as i(city str, current bool)
    on i.current=true
```